# How to evaluate a JavaScript function from a text input

Tags: javascript, parsing, three.js

I have an in-browser particle engine running in THREE.js. I want to add animation functionality, so I have a text input that will contain code, which should be called from my "animate" function which updates the position and other information of the particle emitters.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERO5G.jpg

```
function animate() {

    time = Date.now();

    runCustomAnimateScript();

    for(var i = 0; i < emitters.length; i++){
        emitters[i].updateParticles(deltaTime);
    }

    render();

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
}

function runCustomAnimateScript(){
    //Filled from text input after updateCustomAnimateScript is called
    //Called from within animate (which is run every frame)
}

function updateCustomAnimateScript(){
    //Parse document.querySelectorAll("textarea[name='customAnimateScript']").value 
    //into a script, and enter it into runCustomAnimateScript
}
```

Currently I have no way to turn this text input into an executable JavaScript function. I'm surprised that nobody has tried to do this before, or at least posted about it?

Comment: *I'm surprised that nobody has tried to do this before* That's practically all that [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) does.  The problem is that executing code like this can be somewhat dangerous, especially whenever you evaluate code that could be coming from other users, like if you evaluated message board signatures as JavaScript.  Make sure you only run code that the user supplies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old way you *evaluate* arbitrary code is by using the [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) method.

A better way is to use [`Components.utils.evalInSandbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Language_Bindings/Components.utils.evalInSandbox), but the support may be limited.

```
function runCustomAnimateScript(){
   const sandbox = new Components.utils.Sandbox("http://www.your-url.com/");
   let result = Components.utils.evalInSandbox(document.querySelectorAll("textarea[name='customAnimateScript']").value , sandbox);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, another way to do this is to create a `<script>` tag, set the body of the script to the user's code, and attach the script to the DOM:

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const script = document.createElement("script");
  script.innerHTML = document.querySelector("textarea").value;
  document.body.appendChild(script);
  document.body.removeChild(script);
});
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 500px;
  height: 10em;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea><button type="button">Run</button>
```

Just be careful.  Both this method and `eval()` can open you up to code injection attacks.